# Injecting CSS to a page as soon as possible

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension CSS hides youtube video (on youtube.com) from being displayed. The only issue, it loads only when the page is ready, so a noticeable 1-2 seconds of the video is being showed before it is hidden.

How can I inject CSS before the page even loads? Here is my injection code I tried with no luck:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    path = chrome.runtime.getURL("/inject.css");
    jQuery('<link/>', {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        type: 'text/css',
        href: path
    }).appendTo('head');

});
```

Comment: Replace this entire code with "content_scripts" section with "css":["inject.css"] in manifest.json ([example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#declaratively)) and add "run_at":"document_start" (shown below the example in the linked page).

Comment: Thanks! I already have that, forgot to mention.
`"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.youtube.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js","js/content.js", "js/controller.js"],
      "css": ["css/style.css", "css/inject.css"],
      "run_at" : "document_start"
    }`

Comment: In that case you don't need to insert inject.css in JS. You need to make sure your CSS selectors are correct and match the video also while it's loading. Maybe you need to add `!important`. Anyway, without [MCVE](/help/mcve) we can only guess and it's not the right way to solve such problems.